# PHP / javascript — pass select option data/attributes to function with inline onchange

Tags: javascript, php

How would I pass the selected option from this select:

```
<select name="" id="" onchange="return selectType(// the selected option)">
    <?php foreach ($options as $key => $option) { ?>
      <option
        class=""
        data-optionname="<?= $option["name"] ?>"
        data-patterns="<?= join(",", $option["Pattern"]) ?>"
      >
          <?= $option["name"] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

To this function:

```
<script>
function selectType(option) {
  patterns = $(option).data("patterns").split(",");
  patterns.push(".zip");
  currtype = $(option).data("optionname");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your original code was `selectType(this)`. Why did you changed? Seems the correct approach.

Comment: Must it be an inline `onchange`? Also, there are weird things about the html: `href` attribute on an `option` element and the empty `id` on the `select`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks, I forgot to remove the href -- I'm converting a large radio set of `<a>` elements to a dropdown select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
<select name="" id="" onchange="return selectType(this)">
    <?php foreach ($options as $key => $option) { ?>
      <option href="#"
        class=""
        data-optionname="<?= $option["name"] ?>"
        data-patterns="<?= join(",", $option["Pattern"]) ?>"
      >
          <?= $option["name"] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And your JS:

```
<script>
function selectType(option) {
    alert(option.value);
}
</script>
```

There is your selected element.

If you need to get the data attribute you can use:

```
$(option).find("option:selected").data("optionname");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I access the data- attributes in the function? `data-optionname` and `data-patterns`

Comment: Edited @KirkRoss take a look

Comment: Thank you sir! :)